# resource leak and output file is not writing

Tags: java

I get a resource leak warning in **`return new ArrayList<>();`**. The file is not writing in the friends.txt which I am trying to save list in a text file. Please help.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ReadWrite {

    public void writeFriends(ArrayList<Friend> friends) {
        FileOutputStream friendFile;
        ObjectOutputStream friendWriter;
        try {
            friendFile = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\aa\\Desktop\\src\\friends.txt"));
            friendWriter = new ObjectOutputStream(friendFile);
            if(friends.size() >0) {
                friendWriter.writeInt(friends.size());
                for (Friend friend : friends) {
                    friendWriter.writeObject(friend);
                }
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("No data to write");
            }
            friendWriter.close();
            friendFile.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File Not Found. Retry after creating File 'Friends.txt'");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Stream cannot be initialized.");
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<Friend> readFriends() {
        FileInputStream friendFile;
        ObjectInputStream friendReader;
        ArrayList<Friend> friends = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            friendFile = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\aa\\Desktop\\src\\friends.txt"));
            friendReader = new ObjectInputStream(friendFile);
            int size = friendReader.readInt();
            if(size > 0){
                for (int i = 0; i < friendReader.readInt(); i++) {
                    friends.add((Friend) friendReader.readObject());
                }
            }
            else{
               System.out.println("Empty File");
               return new ArrayList<>();
            }
            friendReader.close();
            friendFile.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File Not Found. Retry after creating File 'Friends.txt'");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Stream cannot be inititalized");
        }
        return friends;
    }
}
```

I am trying to save a list of friends in the friends.txt file. I see no output in the friends.txt file. Is it something to do with my location or `FileOutputStream` ?

Comment: You get that warning, because you are not closing your input stream in the case of an empty file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems in your code.

1. There is a bug in the `for` loop in method `readFriends` of class `ReadWrite`.
2. The file *friends.txt* may not be closed.

Here is the corrected code. Note that I could not find the code for class `Friend` in your question so I wrote a minimal class. Since you are using serialization, I assume that class `Friend` implements interface [Serializable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html).

Notes after the code.

```java
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ReadWrite {
    public void writeFriends(ArrayList<Friend> friends) {
        try (OutputStream friendFile = Files.newOutputStream(Paths.get("C:", "Users", "aa", "Desktop", "src", "friends.dat"));
             ObjectOutputStream friendWriter = new ObjectOutputStream(friendFile)) {
            if (friends.size() > 0) {
                friendWriter.writeInt(friends.size());
                for (Friend friend : friends) {
                    friendWriter.writeObject(friend);
                }
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("No data to write");
            }
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File Not Found. Retry after creating File 'friends.dat'");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Stream cannot be initialized.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<Friend> readFriends() {
        ArrayList<Friend> friends = new ArrayList<>();
        try (InputStream friendFile = Files.newInputStream(Paths.get("C:", "Users", "aa", "Desktop", "src", "friends.dat"));
             ObjectInputStream friendReader = new ObjectInputStream(friendFile)) {
            int size = friendReader.readInt();
            if (size > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                    friends.add((Friend) friendReader.readObject());
                }
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Empty File");
                return new ArrayList<>();
            }
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File Not Found. Retry after creating File 'friends.dat'");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Stream cannot be inititalized");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return friends;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Friend> friends = new ArrayList<>();
        Friend friend = new Friend("Jane");
        friends.add(friend);
        ReadWrite rw = new ReadWrite();
        rw.writeFriends(friends);
        ArrayList<Friend> newFriends = rw.readFriends();
        System.out.println(newFriends);
    }
}

class Friend implements Serializable {
    private String name;

    public Friend(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

In the `for` loop condition in method `readFriends` you have the following:

```java
friendReader.readInt()
```

This means that in every loop iteration, you are trying to read another `int` from the file `friends.txt`. This call fails since there is only one `int` in the file. Hence you need to use `size` which is the variable that contains the only `int` in file `friends.txt` which you read before the `for` loop.

Since you are using serialization, it is recommended to give the file name an extension of `.dat` rather than `.txt` since the file is **not** a text file.

I always write `printStackTrace()` in my `catch` blocks since that helps me to locate the cause of the exception. You actually should not get a `FileNotFoundException` since Java will create the file if it doesn't exist. If Java fails to create the file, then it is probably because the user has no permission to create a file, so displaying an error message saying to create the file before running your code probably won't help.

Your code may successfully open the file and write some data to it and crash before you have written all the data. In that case, your code does not close the file. If you are using at least Java 7, then you should use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) to ensure that the files are always closed.

Java 7 also introduced [NIO.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileio.html) as a better API for interacting with the computer's file system from Java code. I suggest that you use it as I have shown in the code, above.